# Boolearn logic in Python CGI script

Tags: python, html, xml, list

Does anyone know how to set a html check box to true or false with python. I am using a Python file to parse an XML file to a list. From this list I want to check a checkbox if the text in XML tag is 1 or I want it to remain unchecked if the the text in the XML tag is 0.

Thsi is being done as a cgi file, don't ask why. It just is. I can't use any frameworks as this is for a device with a small amount of memory.

The list I have parses the XML file to a list, this part works.

```
 <label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="L10" value="L10" checked="checked" type="checkbox"

    <span> L10  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label>

    <label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="L05" value="1" type="checkbox" checked/>

<span> L5  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label>
```

Can I do something like:

```
if config_settings.settings[11] == '1':
    True
```

Or could I put the logic into the html form something like:

```
<label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="L05" if config.settings.settings[11] == '1':
    <input name="L05" value="1" type="checkbox" checked/>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if config_settings.settings[11] == '1': True` doesn't do anything. It just creates a `True`, does nothing with it and forgets it.

Comment: @JulienBernu Hi Julien thanks for taking a look at my question. Would you have any advice for me on how to proceed, or where to look for further information on this topic?

Comment: I know nothing about xml, all I can say is that the python part doesn't make sense. Also in general I think what you are trying to do is very unclear.

Comment: @JulienBernu Thanks for responding anyway, I'll try and make my questions clearer in future. I figured out a partial answer by the way.

Comment: `if config_settings.settings[11] == '1':
    print'''<html><label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="L05" value="1" type="checkbox" checked/></html>'''
else:
    print'''<html><label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="L05" value="1" type="checkbox"/></html>'''`

Answer (score 0):

I was shown a solution by someone who was using php to do something similiar. The answer that worked for me in the end was simple enough. I changed the setting in the XML file to 1 or 0 for true or false and then did this:

```
if config_settings.settings[5] == '1':

    print'''<html><label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="aWeight" value="1" type="checkbox" checked/></html>'''
else:
    print'''<html><label class="checkbox inline control-label"><input name="aWeight" value="1" type="checkbox"/></html>'''
```

The HTML was inside a Python cgi script.